# Recaptcha error "unexpected token" - Firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, recaptcha

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express')
const request = require('request')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/reserver', (req, res) => {
  if(req.body.captcha === undefined || req.body.captcha === '' || req.body.captcha === null) {
    return res.json({"success": false, "msg": "Bekræft venligst captcha"})
  }

  const secretKey = 'SECRET-KEY'
  const verifyURL = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secretKey}&response=${req.body.captcha}`

  request(verifyURL, (err, response, body) => {
    body = JSON.parse(body)

    if(body.success != undefined && !body.success) {
        return res.json({"success": false, "msg": "Failed captcha verify"})
    }
    return res.json({"success": true, "msg": "Godkendt captcha"})
  })
})

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Im trying to integrate recaptcha onto my website. Im using firebase Cloud functions to verify the recaptcha. The first part of the "app" function, the if statement, runs just fine. But when i complete the recaptcha, hence moving on to request(verifyURL, (err, response, body), it gives me 2 errors. "POST 500" and "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0` -> This is because you are using `JSON.parse(body)` before checking the value of `err` in the callback - always check if there is an error at the start of your callback. The `Unexpected token E` is probably because body is just a simple string response rather than JSON when an error is encountered.

Comment: I still got the error and turned out i had to upgrade my firebase plan to make an outbounded request.. But thank you for your help